# Postfix with office365 integration for sending emails

Tags: email, office365, postfix-mta

I have a CentOS7 server that will be deployed to a customer site. I want to get alerts via emails when something goes wrong on the server.

I have an office365 account so I am thinking whether I can use it as a SMTP relay server. (Forgive me here if my words don't make sense since I have very limited knowledge about SMTP and email related technology).

My first question is, do I need to do anything special with the office365 account? I am using smtp.office365.com:587 as the SMTP relay host.

Here is my postfix main.cf config:

```
relayhost = [smtp.office365.com]:587
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

Here is my "generic" and "sasl_passwd" file look like. I also used the "postmap" to generate the .db file

```
/.*/    <o365 email>
root@server.difan.local <o365 email>
root@localdomain        <o365 email>
@localdomain            <o365 email>

[smtp.office365.com]:587 <o365 email>:<o365 password>
```

This is the command I used to test it

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line"   difan.zhao@outlook.com
```

Here is what I see in /var/log/maillog

```
Mar 26 10:46:00 server postfix/pickup[1921]: 5DC594087202: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar 26 10:46:00 server postfix/cleanup[2495]: 5DC594087202: message-id=<20170326164600.5DC594087202@server.difan.local>
Mar 26 10:46:00 server postfix/qmgr[1922]: 5DC594087202: from=<root@server.difan.local>, size=486, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 26 10:46:00 server postfix/smtp[2497]: warning: SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found
Mar 26 10:46:00 server postfix/smtp[2497]: 5DC594087202: SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.office365.com[40.97.128.34]: no mechanism available
... <last two messages repeated 4 times>
Mar 26 10:46:02 server postfix/smtp[2497]: 5DC594087202: to=<difan.zhao@outlook.com>, relay=smtp.office365.com[40.97.142.194]:587, delay=2.2, delays=0.02/0/2.2/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.office365.com[40.97.142.194]: no mechanism available)
```

Where did I do wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly change your generic files to:

```
/.*/    email@domain.com
```

Secondly verify your generic and sasl permissions:
set the owner and permissions.

```
sudo postmap hash:/etc/postfix/generic 
sudo chown root:root /etc/postfix/generic /etc/postfix/generic.db  
sudo chmod 644 /etc/postfix/generic /etc/postfix/generic.db
```

Same to `sasl_passwd` and `db` file.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the advice.. I ended up have to install these: yum install cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-lib cyrus-sasl-plain. No idea what they are but it works now!

Answer (score 1):

On new versions of Ubuntu/Debian you need install this package: libsasl2-modules

```
apt install libsasl2-modules
```

And then reload postfix

```
systemctl reload postfix
```

Comment: To make your answer more useful you should explain what you are doing and why it's working; also you can use formatting to make your answer more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install these... Not sure what they are but they worked!

yum install cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-lib cyrus-sasl-plain